# How to create Two Applications in Dotnet Domain using (MVC ,WebServices (or) Class Library)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

How can I create Two Applications in Dotnet Domain using (MVC ,WebServices (or) Class Library)?

I want to create Two application

> 1)which is having Database Connection(Developed One)
>
> 2)Client Application - With out Database Connection Need to get the
>   data from Application(1).

May I know which technologies is usefull?

> A) MVC(Through Ajax Call  will Connect) - WebServices(Having Database 
>   Connection)
>
> B) MVC(Through Ajax Call Will Connect)  -Class  Library(BY  Sending
>   Class dll).

So, I need combination of technologies .
In Client Application I don't want a Database connectionstring.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you need a Web Api not an mvc application to interact with db and and client application choice is upto you that can be anything mvc scf spf android

now the main thing is if you use Web Api then you can create multiple client application over multiple platforms without worrying about the code  structure or platform since the webapi can return result in json format

so go for WebAPI for your application